# Chrome , couldn't load Silverlight plugin

Tags: silverlight, google-chrome

Does anybody know how to force SL 5 work in chrome ?

Chrome version is: Version 22.0.1229.94 m

IE 9 working perfect , Chrome gives following message couldn't load Silverlight plugin.

Thanks.

Comment: This is better suited on http://www.superuser.com

Comment: @keyboardP this question is practically illegible, and is _not_ suitable for [SU]. The answer is even worse. **Please do not migrate crap.** It wastes our time on SU when you guys send us low-quality posts like this. Please think twice before migrating.

Comment: Sorry, but I understood it fine. There's an issue with Chrome that throws a message saying `Couldn't load Silverlight plugin`. OP is trying to get SL 5 working in Chrome. It may not be perfect English, but please put some effort into understanding it. Also, SU *is* the place for this type of question (http://superuser.com/search?q=chrome+silverlight). There, you can post a comment asking to clarify if you haven't understood it (or feel free to close it, but at least OP and other readers are aware of the site). We shouldn't discourage non-native speakers IMO.